# how to use put methode on vue js + node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express

hi guys i have a problem ;its how to update username using a text field
the images bellow  describe what i did

first i used a model user.js then a UserController.js then route.js

but  i didn't get how to update username from a text firld  after clic on edit

[this is  the  input vue js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpdMA.png)

[updateUser function in userController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXxWH.png)

[this is the router  file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpYE6.png)

[this is the index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JooZT.png)

Comment: Hi, it is better to add code to your question than using links to images. please consider editing your question so it will be easier for people to help you. please read how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I agree with the comment above. You're making your helpers do too much work to solve your problem. Embed the images and code directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR; You need to send an AJAX request from your client application.

The main problem is that the Vue.js code has nothing to with the back-end code. And the Vue.js application lives in the browser. So the right way to do that will be to define a click handler that will collect the data from a form and then send the AJAX request to the Node.js server on the endpoint that handles user update.